# sqlite3 and bash, database settings

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite

My bash script automates some data input into an sqlite database. The issue I encounter is that every time I change a database setting, the changes are lost when I run the next command. An example will explain this.

```
sqlite3 Correlate.db ".mode csv"
sqlite3 Correlate.db ".output Correlated.csv"
sqlite3 Correlate.db "SELECT * FROM ALL_Data;
sqlite3 Correlate.db ".show"
```

The end result of `.show` is as follows:

```
     echo: off
  explain: off
  headers: off
     mode: list
nullvalue: ""
   output: stdout
separator: "|"
    stats: off
    width:
```

It seems that my changing the output mode to csv has been lost Also my output file has no data, even though stdout is printing the data I want to see. Is it resetting the database settings each time I call it? I'm rather confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like this to send multiple commands to one instance of `sqlite3`:

```sql
sqlite3 Correlate.db <<EOF
.mode csv
.output Correlated.csv
SELECT * FROM ALL_Data;
.show
EOF
```

You could also put these commands in a file and redirect it to the `sqlite3`, e.g.:

```
sqlite3 Correlate.db < commandfile
```

Comment: I was going to use a separate SQL script file, but I needed to use variables with bash. The first suggestion worked perfectly once I fixed my syntax goofs. Thanks for your help!!!